# SQL how to subtract result row 1 from row 2, row 2 from row 3

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns, correlated-subquery

How do I subtract row 1 from row 2 and row 2 from row 3, etc. in MySQL?
The table i am pulling my data from contains multiple products and all products have multiple prices (on different dates)

The code i am working with:

```
 SELECT 
        orderline_sales.product_name,
        orderline_sales.price
    FROM
        orderline_sales         
    GROUP BY price
    HAVING orderline_sales.product_name = 'Ibuprofen';
```

The result I am getting:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      product_name   |     price        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Ibuprofen     |      30.20       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Ibuprofen     |      32.20       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Ibuprofen     |      35.20       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

The result I want:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      product_name   |     price        |   price_change   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       Ibuprofen     |      30.20       |         0        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       Ibuprofen     |      32.20       |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       Ibuprofen     |      35.20       |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: You select 2 columns `orderline_sales.product_name, orderline_sales.price` and you get 2 columns. If you need 3, `SELECT` 3.

Comment: @Alex that is not useful at all, what would he select for the third column given he needs the change from the previous column.  It's doable, but certainly not obvious

Comment: @dave his query is bad itself. `GROUP BY price` should at least be `GROUP BY product_name, price`. And expected result does not provide any explanation about **why** data should include extra column and how it should be calculated. To me the point is OP does not really understand his own query.

Comment: i advice you to read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide example data also.

Comment: and to add to @Alex 's comment SQL in by definition orderless so MySQL does not know which row is 1, 2 or 3 without using `ORDER BY` .. Even if older MySQL versions automatic sort `GROUP BY` queries this feature is removed in MySQL 5.7+

Comment: @Alex When GROUP BY is not used, HAVING behaves like a WHERE clause.  Since he has `HAVING product_name = 'Ibuprofen'`, adding it the group by wouldn't make a difference - anything not in that group is already filtered out.

Comment: dave  i think @Alex means the topicstarter is misusing MySQL's extended `GROUP BY` "feature" which allows you to select columns which are not in the `GROUP BY` and can and will cause **invalid** data for every selected column which is not in the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look into MySQL's [user defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html), and then you probably want to do something like this:

```
SET @prev := NULL;
SELECT
    DATE(created_at),
    price - COALESCE(@prev, price) AS price_change,
    name,
    (@prev := price) AS price FROM (
        SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY DATE(created_at)
    ) t1
GROUP BY
    name, price, DATE(created_at)
HAVING name = 'Ibuprofen'
ORDER BY DATE(created_at);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I haven't checked syntax so it might be a little off but that is the general idea.  Note that I added date so that you can order by it, otherwise the results may be meaningless.

EDIT:

Just ran this on my machine:

```
SET @prev := NULL;
SELECT
    DATE(created_at),
    price - COALESCE(@prev, price) AS price_change,
    name,
    (@prev := price) AS price FROM (
        SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY DATE(created_at)
    ) t1
GROUP BY
    name, price, DATE(created_at)
HAVING name = 'Ibuprofen'
ORDER BY DATE(created_at);

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+------------------+--------------+-----------+-------+
| DATE(created_at) | price_change | name      | price |
+------------------+--------------+-----------+-------+
| 2018-12-10       |            0 | Ibuprofen |   110 |
| 2018-12-13       |          -10 | Ibuprofen |   100 |
| 2018-12-13       |           20 | Ibuprofen |   120 |
+------------------+--------------+-----------+-------+

3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM items;
+----+-------+----------------+---------------------+
| id | price | name           | created_at          |
+----+-------+----------------+---------------------+
|  8 |   100 | Ibuprofen      | 2018-12-13 12:52:35 |
|  9 |   110 | Ibuprofen      | 2018-12-10 12:12:12 |
| 10 |   120 | Ibuprofen      | 2018-12-13 12:52:35 |
| 11 |  1000 | Something else | 2018-12-13 13:01:19 |
+----+-------+----------------+---------------------+

4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Where did you see `date` in OP?

Comment: @Alex I didn't which is why I said "Note that I added date so that you can order by it, otherwise the results may be meaningless."

Comment: It is meaningless even with date. Do you expect only one price to exist in the same `date`? or do you expect `date` to be `datetime`? your approach is not proper or clear still. I see what you are trying to do. But I think you just confuse OP more and more :-)

Comment: :-) very clever dataset `2018-12-13 12:52:35 ` ;-) And having one record in each group - demonstrates very few scenarios I think.

Comment: i agree with @Alex here.. Besides `HAVING name = 'Ibuprofen'` is the relational the "same" as using `WHERE name = 'Ibuprofen'` is this case,  There is not a good reason you should use `GROUP BY` to "unduplicate" `GROUP BY` is designed to work with aggregate functions you didn't use anny in your query.. You should be using `DISTINCT` which is designed to unduplicate.

Comment: Don't you feel guilty for trying to guess what OP need? so you invented `datetime` column for him, then you invented `DATE()` over your invented column for him? You are kind trying to resolve some your own problem, but not OPs? :-)

Comment: I agree it is better to use `WHERE` in this case, my point was and is that it doesn't in practice make a different to the results, nor is the use of one or the other actually relevant to the question.  It's nitpicking, which is not what the site is for.  He clearly wants to calculate the change in price, and I showed him how.  How we choose to filter the results is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @Alex I did resolve OPs problems, and anticipated some things he might not have.  What have you done?

Comment: Not answer the [stackoverflow "guidelines"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) more less "expect" the topicstarter to make a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example... So we don't have to make educated geusses.

Comment: i was hoping you didn't saw that.

Comment: @dave Probably you did not realize, but I helped you to do that. You can refuse to agree. But the fact - I did. ;-) And I still doubt that OP got the solution. He is too silent to make any guess of what is going on. Did you contact with him in chat?

Comment: @Alex well he accepted my answer so I'm guessing I helped.  And what did you help me do, exactly?

Comment: Reread all my comments and check what you've changed in your answer after each one. And compare initial query you've posted vs final version. (which still have questionable parts)

Comment: Well then, if it makes you feel better, you were a great help.  *Well done* Alex, couldn't have done it without you.  The way you complained that date wasn't in the initial question and wondered why I had already added it, and then complained that the dates were the same was very enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could work ?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;

CREATE TABLE test (
product_name text,
price numeric
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES 
('ibuprofen', 30.20),
('ibuprofen', 32.20),
('ibuprofen', 35.20);


SELECT DISTINCT t.product_name, t.current_price - t.previous_price AS price_change
FROM (SELECT te.product_name, te.price AS current_price, 
         LAG(te.price) over w  AS previous_price, 
         row_number() over w AS rn
         FROM test AS te 
         WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY te.product_name, te.price)
         ) AS t
WHERE t.product_name = 'ibuprofen'
AND t.rn <> 1
ORDER BY t.product_name, price_change;
```

This Query returns following result:

```
 product_name | price_change 
--------------+--------------
 ibuprofen    |         0.00
 ibuprofen    |         2.00
 ibuprofen    |         3.00
```

Comment: I like `LAG()` mentioned in this context. Is it available starting from MySQL 5.7 only?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the original purpose was to track price changes (time/id). Assuming the GROUP BY was there to eliminate rows where price has not changed. You could do following (variation of @dave 's answer):

```
SELECT product_name, price, cast( ifnull(price_change,0) as decimal(6,2)) as price_change
FROM (
SELECT
    product_name,
    price - @prev AS price_change,
    (@prev := price) AS price
FROM
    orderline_sales
    JOIN (SELECT @prev := null) as j
WHERE orderline_sales.product_name = 'Ibuprofen' 
ORDER BY id
) as q
WHERE price_change is null or price_change!=0;
```

The difference to @dave's answer is the removal of incorrect use of `GROUP BY`.

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3x2yrBnPpfYK8mhDEECYvo/0).

Comment: @Alex, as said there likely is an order of the rows, otherwise the whole question would not make sense. The column defining the order being datetime / id or whatever does not really matter. If there is no order for the columns, there is no correct answer for the question.