# MySQL Get Change From Cumulative Results in Consecutive Rows by Identifier

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I am running MySQL Community Server version 8.0.19.

I have been struggling with the following problem whilst working through publicly available COVID19 data. I am using a dataset that is both reliable and of good quality, however the data (total_confirmed) is reported using **cumulative** totals instead of daily counts of infections:

```
+----------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| country_region | date                | total_confirmed |
+----------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| Afghanistan    | 2020-04-05 00:00:00 |             349 |
| Afghanistan    | 2020-04-06 00:00:00 |             367 |
| Afghanistan    | 2020-04-07 00:00:00 |             423 |
| Albania        | 2020-04-05 00:00:00 |             361 |
| Albania        | 2020-04-06 00:00:00 |             377 |
| Albania        | 2020-04-07 00:00:00 |             383 |
| Algeria        | 2020-04-05 00:00:00 |            1320 |
| Algeria        | 2020-04-06 00:00:00 |            1423 |
| Algeria        | 2020-04-07 00:00:00 |            1468 |
+----------------+---------------------+-----------------+
```

My requirement is to have both the cumulative count and the daily new cases. There is an excellent solution for doing this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53769621/sql-how-to-subtract-result-row-1-from-row-2-row-2-from-row-3) and it works like a charm on my dataset provided that I focus on one country only (I used a table populated with Afghanistan data only in this example):

```
SET @prev := NULL;

SELECT country_region
      ,`date` AS DateCreated
      ,total_confirmed - coalesce(@prev, total_confirmed) AS new_cases
      ,(@prev := total_confirmed) AS total_confirmed
FROM (
        SELECT * FROM so_confirmed ORDER BY `date`
     ) t1
GROUP BY
     country_region, total_confirmed, `date`
ORDER BY country_region, DateCreated;
```

Output:

```
+----------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| country_region | DateCreated         | new_cases | total_confirmed |
+----------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| Afghanistan    | 2020-04-05 00:00:00 |         0 |             349 |
| Afghanistan    | 2020-04-06 00:00:00 |        18 |             367 |
| Afghanistan    | 2020-04-07 00:00:00 |        56 |             423 |
+----------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

However, the minute more than one country_region exists in the data, it completely fails and I do not know SQL quite well enough to figure out what I need to change.

```
+----------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| country_region | DateCreated         | new_cases | total_confirmed |
+----------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| Afghanistan    | 2020-04-05 00:00:00 |         0 |             349 |
| Afghanistan    | 2020-04-06 00:00:00 |      -953 |             367 |
| Afghanistan    | 2020-04-07 00:00:00 |     -1000 |             423 |
| Albania        | 2020-04-05 00:00:00 |        12 |             361 |
| Albania        | 2020-04-06 00:00:00 |        10 |             377 |
| Albania        | 2020-04-07 00:00:00 |       -40 |             383 |
| Algeria        | 2020-04-05 00:00:00 |       959 |            1320 |
| Algeria        | 2020-04-06 00:00:00 |      1046 |            1423 |
| Algeria        | 2020-04-07 00:00:00 |      1085 |            1468 |
+----------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+----------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| country_region | DateCreated         | new_cases | total_confirmed |
+----------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| Afghanistan    | 2020-04-05 00:00:00 |         0 |             349 |
| Afghanistan    | 2020-04-06 00:00:00 |        18 |             367 |
| Afghanistan    | 2020-04-07 00:00:00 |        56 |             423 |
| Albania        | 2020-04-05 00:00:00 |         0 |             361 |
| Albania        | 2020-04-06 00:00:00 |        16 |             377 |
| Albania        | 2020-04-07 00:00:00 |         6 |             383 |
| Algeria        | 2020-04-05 00:00:00 |         0 |            1320 |
| Algeria        | 2020-04-06 00:00:00 |       103 |            1423 |
| Algeria        | 2020-04-07 00:00:00 |        45 |            1468 |
+----------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Obviously in a real-world dataset the new_cases values wouldn't be 0 on 2020-04-05, but in this sample dataset that would be correct.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: I am running MySQL Community Server version 8.0.19. I will also update the original post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with window function `lag()`:

```
select
    sc.*,
    coalesce(
        total_confirmed - lag(total_confirmed) over(partition by country_region order by datecreated),
        0
    ) new_cases
from so_confirmed sc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the three argument form of `lag()`:

```
select sc.*,
       (total_confirmed -
        lag(total_confirmed, 1, total_confirmed) over (partition by country_region order by date_created)
       ) as new_cases
from so_confirmed sc;
```

In older versions of MySQL, you can use a join, assuming that there are no missing dates:

```
select sc.*,
       coalesce(sc.total_confirmed - sc_prev.total_confirmed, 0) as new_cases
from so_confirmed sc left join
     so_confirmed sc_prev
     on sc_prev.country_region = sc.country_region and
        sc_prev.datecreated = sc.datecreated - interval 1 day;
```